# Marionette events are not triggered on Route

Tags: marionette

Why Marionette events are not triggered when I access a URL?

When I access the URL it suppose to call the function `API.goHome()`

but it doesn't! I don't understand why?

Here is my Code:

App.js

```
var PatientPortal = new Marionette.Application();

PatientPortal.addRegions({
    'headerRegion': '#header',
    'bodyRegion': '#body',
    'footerRegion': '#footer'
});

PatientPortal.on("before:start", function () {

    console.log("Started");

});

PatientPortal.navigate = function (route, options) {
    options || (options = {});
    Backbone.history.navigate(route, options);
};

PatientPortal.getCurrentRoute = function () {
    return Backbone.history.fragment
};

PatientPortal.on("start", function(){

    if (Backbone.history) {
        Backbone.history.start();
    }

    if(PatientPortal.getCurrentRoute() == ""){
        PatientPortal.navigate('home');
    }


});

PatientPortal.start();
```

and Router Code:

```
PatientPortal.module("Portal", function (Portal, PatientPortal, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
    Portal.Router = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
        controller: "API",
        appRoutes: {
            "": "goHome",
            "home": "goHome"
        }
    });

    var API = {
        goHome: function () {
            console.log("go home");
        }
    };

    PatientPortal.on("home:route", function () {
        console.log("OKOKOK")
        API.goHome();
    });

    PatientPortal.addInitializer(function () {
        new Portal.Router({
            controller: API
        });
    });
});
```

and here a home page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>INSAH - Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="header"></div>

    <script src="./js/assets/provider/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/assets/provider/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/assets/provider/backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/assets/provider/backbone/backbone.babysitter.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/assets/provider/backbone/backbone.wreqr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/assets/provider/marionette/backbone.marionette.min.js"></script>


    <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/routes/route.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is your app actually started? In my home page code I have to call a function to actually start it - 
  $(function() {
    PatientPortal.start({
    });
  });'

Comment: Also what happens if you add a log statement to your addInitializer statement where you add the router as an initializer? Does that actually happen?

Comment: @TomHammond Yes it starts, and yes i see that the addInitializer function is called, and the Portal.Router object is created as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, it was because of starting the backbone history, the AddInitializer functuion shoudl be as following:

```
PatientPortal.addInitializer(function () {
    new Portal.Router({
        controller: API
    });
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

and we should remove this line from app.js:

```
    Backbone.history.start();
```